# .htaccess mod_rewrite not working as expected ( redirect to folder )

Tags: loops, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

# REDIRECT BASE URL TO INDEX ( http://www.example.com )
RewriteRule ^$ page/index/ [L]

# If URL CONTAINS API REDIRECT TO APPLICATION DIRECTORY ( http://www.example.com/api?test=1 )
RewriteRule ^api application/ [L]

# GOTO THE DIRECTORY ( http://www.example.com/login )
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) page/$1 [L]

# IF FILE OR DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST REDIRECT TO ERROR404 ( http://www.example.com/doesnotexist )
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) page/error404/ [L]
```

My file structure is :

***Application ( folder )***

***Page ( folder : Holding other folders I.E login folder )***

***.htaccess ( file )***

The problem :

If **GOTO THE DIRECTORY** section is present it all fails to work ( looping ), but If I remove this section it works.  How would I make the GOTO THE DIRECTORY section play nice with the others.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to actually redirect the browser? 

If so you need to specify a redirect code. e.g. `RewriteRule (.*) page/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: No it should work in the background